# How to secure a passport in a BNB

Tags: passports, europe

I am looking for good ideas for securing a passport, other credentials and extra money in a BNB without a safe. In particular I stay for extended durations in the same AirBNB and do not want to carry my passport with me when not necessary.

Mostly Italy currently but also Switzerland, France, Netherlands, UK.

Comment: Define not necessary. What happens if some crisis happens while you're out (terrorist attack, riot, etc) and you need to get to the embassy. It is wise (and perhaps law?) to always have your passport on your person when in a foreign country.

Comment: What would you like to keep it secure from? Are you afraid of thieves, fires, earthquakes, aliens?

Comment: My concern at a BNB is theft. The issue with carrying all the time is possible lots perhaps through theft, also annoying on month-long stays at the same location. For ID I carry a Passport Card, it is an official government issued ID.